Spectral analysis for harmonic oscillator operator?
Let $L=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2, x\in\mathbb R$, the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator; this is an unbounded self-adjoint operator acting in $L^2(\mathbb R)$.
I am looking for a reference that deals with the spectral analysis fo the operator $L$, i.e. its spectrum, resolvent and eigenfunctions...
Thank you in advance

This MathOverflow Q&A might be of use to you, including the reference to Kato therein: https://mathoverflow.net/q/278568/55904
